# range reference always to worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I have an excel document in which a certain named range refers to a range:

```
=RWS_Keuzeparameters!$C$15
```

I assume this refers to worksheet RWS_Keuzeparameters but I cannot find or unlock a worksheet with this name. The document has an add-in with an entry screen in which the value in =RWS_Keuzeparameters!$C$15 can be entered. Is it possible the value is only available in this entry screen? Or should there be a worksheet named 'RWS_Keuzeparameters'?

I cannot get into the programmecode because it asks for a password I don't have.

[image: named range specification]

Comment: There must be a worksheet with that name. It may have its visible property set to `xlSheetVeryHidden` in which case you will not be able to unhide it through the UI.

Comment: thanks. I was looking at the named range properties and it also says after the column 'reference' (=RWS_Keuzeparameters!$C$15) for 'range': worksheet where other named ranges have the names of the worksheets mentioned.

Comment: That means the name was defined with workbook scope, not worksheet-level scope. It's the same for your second reference to 'Prijzenboek'